# What is illegal about my app?

Tags: copyright, licensing, right-of-publicity

I want to create an app similar to the [**4shared Music**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.forshared.music&hl=en) app that enables downloading MP3 files stored on my server.

Features

- Serves all mp3 files from host server
- Distributed via [**Google Play Store**](https://play.google.com/store)
- Music library searchable by title or artist name
- Annual subscription fee for unlimited downloads
- Free live music streaming
- MP3 files accessed from content creator or wholesale distributor via API

What might be illegal about what I have described? What might it be wise to consider when building and distributing this app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you are not infringing upon the copyrights of the music owners.

There might be other things you need to do. But at a minimum you will need to have agreements with the music owners that specify the timing and amount of the payments they will receive for allowing you to distribute their music. And any other ancillary terms you or they might want to include depending on the details of your business model.

Comment: And from historical experience, if they don't like what you are doing, they will come down on you like a hammer.